# Iterating over subdirectories: How do I recover if a command in one fails?

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have this for loop

```
for repository in ./*/; do
    echo $repository && cd $repository && git checkout -b prod  && cd - >/dev/null;
done
```

But if branch prod already exists it prints a message and exit the loop.
How can ignore this error and just go to the next directory ?

Thanks

Comment: Using `cd -` in a script is a code smell. Scope your directory change to a subshell and it'll be automatically undone when the subshell exits.

Comment: BTW, git branches exist as filesystem objects -- you can look at whether one named `prod` exists with `[ -e .git/logs/refs/heads/prod ]`, for example.

Comment: Also, it's not true that your original code would _exit the loop_ on the failure. What it would do is to try to do the `cd`s for other loop elements in the wrong directory; but they did still run, just in the wrong place so those runs failed almost immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is that `git checkout -b prod` returns failure to the shell if the branch already exists. Since it's connected to the next command (`cd -`) with the conditional operator `&&`, that next command only runs if `git` succeeds. So when `git` fails, the `cd` doesn't run, and your shell is left in the wrong directory to continue its loop.

In general, when you want your code to continue even if a command fails, separate the commands with `;` or newlines instead of `&&`.

But a better solution in this case is to just do the `cd` in a subshell so that it doesn't affect the outer loop's working directory and you don't have to `cd -` at all:

```
for repository in ./*/; do
   echo "$repository" && (
    cd "$repository" && git checkout -b prod
   )
done
```

That will work fine even if the branch creation fails. It will still print out the error message; if you don't want to see those, add the redirect:

```
 for repository in ./*/; do
   echo "$repository" && (
    cd "$repository" && git checkout -b prod
   ) 2>/dev/null
done
```

I've also quoted the expansion of `$repository` in the commands, which you should almost always do in shell scripts. With the unquoted version, you would get an error if any of the repo directory names had spaces in them, for instance.

Also, that "no side effects in a subshell" thing is great for doing part of your work in a different directory, but it applies more widely. If you had a more complicated loop that set any shell variables or anything while it was in the subdir, those would also be lost. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
home=$PWD
for repository in "$home"/*/; do
    basename "$repository" # to 'echo' $repository
    cd "$repository" && git checkout -b prod
done
```

Comment: thanks it's working great. 
Is there a way to still echo the output but without breaking the loop ?

Comment: I'd consider `echo "${repository##*/}"` to do that more efficiently (without needing to start `/bin/basename` or any other tool that isn't included as part of bash).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, me to, but in this loop `echo "${repository##*/}"` will give empty output.

Comment: Ahh, yes; you'd need `repository=${repository%/}` first.

Answer (score 1):

Better use `pushd` and `popd` and additionally it is saver to use `find`:

```
while read -r repository; do
  pushd "${repository}"
  if git checkout -b prod; then
     echo "git checkout success"
  else
     echo "git chechout error"
  fi
  popd
done < <( find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print )
```

Comment: Even pushd and popd are worse practice than just `(cd ... && ...)`, which will make the `cd` be undone when the `)` happens.

Comment: Depends, the `( )` start a new subprocess and this makes it hard if you want to change content of variables inside. But you are right, in this case it does not matter.

Comment: The subprocess can just be more tightly scoped in that case, to not include anything that changes the shell's state. `git` itself is an external command, after all; `if (cd ... && exec git ...); then ...` doesn't have any more `fork()`s than you already had with just `if git ...`, but it solves the OP's problem.

Comment: BTW, if you're going to use `find` for "safety reasons", might as well go all the way and change from `-print` to `-print0`, and thus from `while read -r repository` to `while IFS= read -r -d '' repository`; that'll fix support for names with not just newlines, but also ones with leading or trailing whitespace. I'm not really sure what's wrong with the OP's original code using a glob, though; it's `ls` that's malpractice.